# JQuery Ajax Request With PHP Validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, validation

I saw this code somewhere without the PHP backend for it and have wondering how to recreate the PHP to validate my forms using this code:

```
$('input.signup-input[name=username]').blur(function () {
    var input = $('input.signup-input[name=username]');
    var validation = input.parent().parent().children('td.validation');
    $.post("/validate.php", {
        cmd: "verify-username",
        username: input.val()
    }, function (data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            validation.html('<div class="success"></div>');
            input.removeClass('error-input');
        } else {
            validation.html('<div class="error">' + data.error + '</div>');
            input.addClass('error-input');
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

In my PHP would I just $_POST a `verify-username` variable and then echo `success` if the field passes validation?

And if the field encounters an error would I have to json_encode an `error` variable in PHP so that it can be put into the `data.error` location of this jquery?

Anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: You answered everything yourself.

Except you would RETRIEVE the post variable in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by RETRIEVE?

Comment: Well in you said you would $_POST the username variable, but that is what JS is doing. In PHP you would get the variable by accessing the $_POST array.

Comment: Hah sorry, I simply misunderstood what you were trying to say. Thanks though for confirming that I had got my information correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right. Just a note though... you don't have to use json since you are simply passing text and validating it. You can use the simple text/html method. Json is used when you use arrays.